# Can't run django app with rest api on Heroku

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I Just created an account on "Heroku.com" and followed the steps in the guide to create a new python project. I cloned the files locally and added a new app to the project and I created a rest api. I added 'rest_framework' to my "settings.py" and I was able to run the project locally. When I tried to push the changes back to heroku, it fails and i get this message:

```
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 632 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:
remote: Package django found!
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in 
execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
remote:            django.setup()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
remote:            apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
remote:            app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
remote:            module = import_module(entry)
remote:          File 
"/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in 
import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, 
level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in 
_gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in 
_find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 948, in 
_find_and_load_unlocked
remote:        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'
remote:
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --
noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote:
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this 
error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote:
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to xplearner.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/xplearner.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/xplearner.git'
```

When I remove 'rest_framework' from my 'settings.py' I can successfully push my changes to "Heroku" but I can no more run the app locally since it won't find restframework in my settings and in the same case, I get this error when i try to launch the project online on Heroku:

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /admin/
No module named 'rest_framework'
```

Please can someone suggest a solution to this problem? What am I not doing right?

Comment: It looks like you forgot to add `rest_framework` to your `requirements.txt` file. Can you show that to us?

Comment: BTW in PyPI `rest_framework` is listed as `djangorestframework`.

Comment: I didn't add restframework to my requirements.txt file. I just did and I also had to apply migrations to my heroku app and it worked fine. thanks very much,  I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a *python2/python3* problem. You can change `rest_framework` with `djangorestframework`If you use python3 with this package locally, can you spesify a little more information about requirements and heroku confs.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The problem was with my requirements.txt file. I didn't add restframework to it.  Thanks,  I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

For me, having it in requirements.txt was not enough. This is a fresh deployment of a new app, and I've never seen anything like this before, but I had to add the requirements to Pipfile. To do this, I used `pipenv install` within my virtual environment. Then just I just added and commited the Pipfile.